# Toggle change with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to change `fa-bars` to `fa-times` when `menu-button` is clicked.

How do I do this with my current code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('nav.primary').prepend('<div id="menu-button">Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>');
      $('nav.primary #menu-button').on('click', function(){
          var menuItems = $(".menu-header-container");
          menuItems.toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: You can use .is( ":visible" ) and is( ":hidden" ) to test the state of toggle element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

```
$('nav.primary #menu-button').on('click', function(){
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times')
});
```

Comment: Upvoted. Correct and complete answer, explained the function used and linked to the source.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.toggleClass('fa-bars fa-time')` (or `$.addClass('fa-bars').removeClass('fa-times');`

Also I recommend to change event binding to

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu-button', function(){
```

Comment: Just curious, Why do you recommend to `bind` the event to `document` rather than directly to the `element` itself? There's no evidence that the element was dynamically added to the DOM.

Comment: @gmo One line higher `append()` adds same element. And since ID must be unique, it's same element. Also, if you are using `.on` most likely it's dynamic elements.

Comment: Not completely agree. As you say, *one line higher*... .prepend() is executed immediately (before) and the object is already in the DOM when the bind event is call.. Also the .on() method (since jQv1.7) provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers (selector string is optional). Any way, there's no harm in using it *I think*. As I say, just was curious to see if I miss something for using it in this case. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggle` with the two classes you wan to change:

```
$('#menu-button i').toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('nav.primary #menu-button').on('click', function(){
  var el = $(this).find('.fa-bars');
  el.removeClass('fa-bars').addClass('fa-times');
});
```